# VLC player fails with python errors

Tags: python, vlc, multimedia

Unable to import files and play any audio video file also unable to install VLC player. Showing following error:

> Required plugin could not be found. Python (v2.7) requires to install
>   plugins to play media files of the following type: MPEG-1 Layer 3
>   (MP3) decoder.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you don't have media codecs. Try installing `ubuntu-restricted-extras`

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```